# Macro/VBA Code to List and print names and code of all macros in a workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007
For this question the name of my workbook is PrintCode.xlsm

Is there a Macro or VBA Code that will print all of the macro names and code within the open workbook?

I have found a few examples on the web but none seem to work?

Comment: So you want to extract all the VBA in the XLSM into a document/print it? For what purpose may I ask?

Comment: If it could also list my VBA (non-macro) code that would be very helpful

Comment: spikey-richie: I am creating a complex worksheet that has 26+ macros and various VBA code. I find that I an getting confused by what I have already done and having a list of the names together with the code would be a great visual aidf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this one, look as it's what you need: [How to retrieve the names of macros from an Excel workbook by using Visual Basic 6.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/315731/how-to-retrieve-the-names-of-macros-from-an-excel-workbook-by-using-vi):

Define a click event handler procedure for the button. Use the following code for this procedure, to display information about the macros that are defined in C:\Abc.xls:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    ' Declare variables to access the Excel workbook.
    Dim objXLApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objXLWorkbooks As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim objXLABC As Excel.Workbook

    ' Declare variables to access the macros in the workbook.
    Dim objProject As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim objComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim objCode As VBIDE.CodeModule

    ' Declare other miscellaneous variables.
    Dim iLine As Integer
    Dim sProcName As String
    Dim pk As vbext_ProcKind

    ' Open Excel, and open the workbook.
    Set objXLApp = New Excel.Application
    Set objXLWorkbooks = objXLApp.Workbooks    
    Set objXLABC = objXLWorkbooks.Open("C:\ABC.XLS")

    ' Empty the list box.
    List1.Clear

    ' Get the project details in the workbook.
    Set objProject = objXLABC.VBProject

    ' Iterate through each component in the project.
    For Each objComponent In objProject.VBComponents

        ' Find the code module for the project.
        Set objCode = objComponent.CodeModule

        ' Scan through the code module, looking for procedures.
        iLine = 1
        Do While iLine < objCode.CountOfLines
            sProcName = objCode.ProcOfLine(iLine, pk)
            If sProcName <> "" Then
                ' Found a procedure. Display its details, and then skip 
                ' to the end of the procedure.
                List1.AddItem objComponent.Name & vbTab & sProcName
                iLine = iLine + objCode.ProcCountLines(sProcName, pk)
            Else
                ' This line has no procedure, so go to the next line.
                iLine = iLine + 1
            End If
        Loop
        Set objCode = Nothing
        Set objComponent = Nothing
    Next

    Set objProject = Nothing

    ' Clean up and exit.
    objXLABC.Close
    objXLApp.Quit
End Sub
```